# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452

Tags: php, mysql, symfony-1.4

I have a problem with my database. When I'm creating a post and choose category, I read:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`apka`.`post`, CONSTRAINT `post_kategoria_kategorie_name` FOREIGN KEY (`kategoria`) REFERENCES `kategorie` (`name`) ON DELETE CASCADE).

This is my schema.yml:

```
Kategorie:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    name: { type: string(255), notnull: true, unique: true }
Post:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    user_id:      { type: string(155), notnull: true }
    kategoria:    { type: string(255) }
    tresc_postu:  { type: string(4000), notnull: true }
    publiczny:    { type: boolean, notnull: true, default: 1 }
  relations:
    Kategorie: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: kategoria, foreign: name, foreignAlias: Category }
```

and data from

```
# categories.yml
Kategorie:
  sport:
    name: Sport
  muzyka:
    name: Muzyka
  internet:
    name: Internet
```

I want choose in my form Post Categories, ex. Sport, Muzyka, Internet. How can I solve this problem?
Thank you for help!

Comment: Value which you are inserting may not be available in master table that by it is giving foreign key constraints fails error

Comment: So.. What I should do? How it will work correctly?

Comment: Provide proper values or check the values before inserting into table that it is available in master table or not, if available then fine else insert it into master table first and then in the second table

Comment: Are you using a form? Post it.

Comment: [link](http://zapodaj.net/4e4ac122f333b.png.html) , it looks good.. but [link](http://zapodaj.net/5861c80e1c08a.png.html)

Comment: You can't insert a record if the field in the **other table** with that value doesn't exist. The table 1 refers to a value in table 2. Because it **refers** to it, it's called **referential integrity**. The solution is not to insert something that doesn't exist.

Comment: Mijh, I'm sorry, but SQL is quite difficult for me. So, that means, my Foreign key is bad? If yes, how do it correctly? Hmm, how would you do second table about Categories?

Answer (score 1):

The error is rather explicit :)

Check Server Error Codes and Messages MYSQL for know the returned typeof error

MySql 5.7 docs : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_no_referenced_row_2

Good luck